# How to evaluate word2vec build on a specific context files

Tags: machine-learning, nltk, word2vec, gensim, feature-engineering

Using gensim word2vec, built a CBOW model with a bunch of litigation files for representation of word as vector in a Named-Entity-recognition problem, but I want to known how to evaluate my representation of words. If I use any other datasets like wordsim353(NLTK) or other online datasets of google, it doesn't work because I built the model specific to my domain dataset of files. How do I evaluate my word2vec's representation of word vectors .I want words belonging to similar context to be closer in vector space.How do I ensure that the build model is doing it ?

I started by using a techniques called **odd one out**. Eg:

```python
model.wv.doesnt_match("breakfast cereal dinner lunch".split()) --> 'cereal'
```

I created my own dataset(for validating) using the words in the training of word2vec .Started evaluating with taking three words of similar context and an odd word out of context.But the accuracy of my model is only 30 % .

Will the above method really helps in evaluating my w2v model ? Or Is there a better way ?

I want to go with word_similarity measure but I need a reference score(Human assessed) to evaluate my model or is there any techniques to do it? Please ,do suggest any ideas or techniques .

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately this depends on the purpose you intend for the word-vectors – your evaluation should mimic the final use as much as possible.

The "odd one out" approach may be reasonable. It's often done with just 2 words that are somehow, via external knowledge/categorization, known to be related (in the aspects that are important for your end use), then a 3rd word picked at random.

If you think your hand-crafted evaluation set is of high-quality for your purposes, but your word-vectors aren't doing well, it may just be that there are other problems with your training: too little data, errors in preprocessing, poorly-chosen metaparameters, etc.

You'd have to look at individual failure cases in more detail to pick what to improve next. For example, even when it fails at one of your odd-one-out tests, do the lists of most-similar words, for each of the words included, still make superficial sense in an eyeball-test? Does using more data or more training iterations significantly improve the evaluation scoring?

A common mistake during both training and evaluation/deployment is to retain too many rare words, on the (mistaken) intuition that "more info must be better". In fact, words with only a few occurrences can't get very high-quality vectors. (Compared to more-frequent words, their end vectors are more heavily influenced by the random original initialization, and by the idiosyncracies of their few occurrences available rather than their most-general meaning.) And further, their presence tends to interfere with the improvement of other nearby more-frequent words. Then, if you include the 'long tail' of weaker vectors in your evaluations, they tend to somewhat arbitrarily intrude in rankings ahead of common words with strong vectors, hiding the 'right' answers to your evaluation questions.

Also, note that the *absolute* value of an evaluation score may not be that important, because you're just looking for something that points your other optimizations *in the right direction* for your true end-goal. Word-vectors that are just slightly-better at precise evaluation questions might still work well-enough in other fuzzier information-retrieval contexts.